# Verifying csproj resources. Namespace references?

Tags: c#, csproj, system.reflection

I have made a small application which generates code for verifying that another applications referenced libraries exist.

The problem i have though is related to the csproj-file itself.

I have noticed that the core-libraries don't have Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken specified.

Without that information i cannot load the assemblies without using a deprecated method in the .Net-Framework. (Assembly.LoadWithPartialName)

Since the core-libraries always should exist, this shouldn't be a problem.

However i cant be sure that this only applies to the core-libraries.

So my question is:

Can i safely assume that this only applies to core-libraries which always should exist on any windows-machine?
And if not, how should i go about loading those assemblies using only their namespace?(Since this is all that is provided in the .csproj-file)

The .Net-framework obviously does the matching in the background somehow or else there would be a more explicit reference somewhere in the .csproj-file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have so far Found out that this applies to libraries which are part of the .Net-Framework and references to projects within the same solution.
As of now im relying on this and if i run in to any problems i will report them here.
A better answer is still very much welcome!